# Need help with expectation question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X$ follows $Po(λ)$, show that $E(X(X-1)(X-2)...(X-k))=λ^{k+1}$.

How do I go about manipulating the definition of $E(X)$ to solve this question?

Comment: Apply $\mathbb Ef(X)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f(n)P(X=n)$. Have a good look at the terms of the sum in this special case.

Comment: Hint please, I've spent 2 hours thinking already.

Comment: $Po(\lambda)$ stands for Poisson distribution, right?

Comment: My first comment was exactly what you asked for: a hint.

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathbb EX(X-1)\cdots(X-k)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)\cdots(n-k)P(X=n)=$$$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(n-1)\cdots(n-k)e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}=$$$$\lambda^{k+1}\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n-k-1}}{(n-k-1)!}=\lambda^{k+1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}$$

Do recognize $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}$?